# How to create VBA to navigate directly to the first row containing a specified value

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to create a VBA macro I can attach to a button at the top of my worksheet in Excel 2010 that navigates to the first row containing a specific value located in column H.

(***Note***: there are several rows with what looks to be empty cells within the visible range because there are a few hidden columns containing formulas that span the whole dataset range. So if the dataset range was from A1:J2000, then rows 900 through 920 may "appear" empty though there are some hidden columns with with formulas. I mention this because the code that attempts to search by a "control-shift-down" method will not work because that would stop short of the actual true range of the dataset.)

I've attempted researching this and have found some scripts that either return the number of the row or something that inserts data. But, nothing for just navigating to the first row that contains a specific value.

In summation, what I would like is the VBA macro to find the first row which contains the word "re-populate" in column H. When that row is found, I would like the VBA macro to select the cell within column B of the corresponding row where the result was located.

Example: If the macro found the word "re-populate" in cell H864, then it would navigate to cell B864.

Comment: Use `Application.Match` to return the row number, then build the range address with `"B"` and use `Select`.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to help me with the total VBA code you would build using the above examples?